# Nested sort in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, cygwin

I'm trying to join one standard input with an unsorted file, let's say:

```
awk '{print $1}' somefile | join /dev/stdin unsortedfile
```

Is it possible to sort the file "at the moment" instead sorting it, saving it and subsequently using it in join? I was thinking about something like

```
export SORT = `sort unsortedfile`; awk '{print $1}' somefile | join /dev/stdin $SORT
```

but it doesn't work, it says "SORT : command not found". I'm new to variables, so I'm not sure they are what I am looking for.

If it can be useful, I'm using cygwin.

Comment: Note that you can't have spaces around assignments in shell scripts.  Capturing the output from `sort` in a variable is unlikely to be a good way of proceeding.  Note that you can often use `-` as a command line argument (all on its own) to indicate 'standard input' (or sometimes standard output, or in the case of GNU Tar, `tar -cf - -T -` uses both standard output — the first one — and standard input — the second one).

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler, I didn't know that. Shorthands are always very welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cool trick for this would be using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) like so:

```
awk '{print $1}' somefile | join /dev/stdin <(sort unsortedfile)
```

The `<(…)` syntax creates a pipe for the duration of the command and allows you to treat the output of a command as a file for just this purpose.

Comment: The `<(…)` notation is called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).  The whole point of the notation is to give a file name to the command (`join` in the example) that is actually the piped output from another command (`sort` in the example). As such, it is not formally anonymous; it has a name such as `/dev/fd/3`.   I left this diatribe out of your answer, but was sorely tempted.

Comment: Note that this can also be used for the `awk` process as well: `join <(awk ...) <(sort unsortedfile)`.

Comment: @AIVaz: Ha! That really makes the thing! Thank you for your quick answer, it was straight and simple!

Comment: I removed the reference to 'unnamed pipe', since process substitution is essentially syntactic sugar for a named pipe that hides the details of what the name is.